# embjerjs select from dynamic data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I am using ember-cli without ember-data.

I have a form that requires a select drop down that is generated from some data from an api response. this is the api response:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "host"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "cPanel"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "website"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm using ember select view to generate the drop down:

```
{{view "select" content=groups optionValuePath="content.id" optionLabelPath="content.name"}}
```

here is my controller:

```
groups: function(){
            var self = this;
            var model = this.get('model');
            var adapter = AddCredentialAdapter.create();
            var groups = adapter.findGroups(model.company_slug);
            return groups.then(function(response){
                return response;
            });
    }.property('credentialGroups', 'model')
```

I keep getting the error:

```
Assertion Failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed {_id: 91, _label: undefined, _state: undefined, _result: undefined, _subscribers: }
```

so I tried doing this:

```
groups: function(){
            var self = this;
            var model = this.get('model');
            var adapter = AddCredentialAdapter.create();
            var groups = adapter.findGroups(model.company_slug);
            return groups.then(function(response){
                return response.map(function(c){
                    return {
                        id: c.id,
                        name: c.name
                    }
                });
            });
    }.property('credentialGroups', 'model')
```

But for some reason the promise is still what is being passed to the view and I get the same error:

```
Assertion Failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed {_id: 91, _label: undefined, _state: undefined, _result: undefined, _subscribers: }
```

if I `console.log(response);` I don't get a promise. I get this instead:

```
[Object, Object, Object, _super: function, nextObject: function, firstObject: Object, lastObject: Object, contains: function…]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah you are definitely trying to set the content property of the `select` with a promise. A computed property doesn't block on return of a promise like you are hoping it will here. The workaround:

```
groups: null,
setGroups: function(){
     var self = this;
     var model = this.get('model');
     var adapter = AddCredentialAdapter.create();
     var groups = adapter.findGroups(model.company_slug);
     groups.then(function(response){
         self.set('groups', response);
     });
}.observes('credentialGroups', 'model'),
//not sure how select handles null
initialize: function(){
    this.set('groups', []);
}.on('init')
```

The idea here is that the select takes a property that is set by a function that observes changes in the dependent keys. The initialize code may or may not be necessary.